# Declaring variables using other variables in the same object

Tags: javascript, variables

I was wondering how to declare new variables by accessing variable values in the same object.  I tried `this.x` and `object.x`. Both say `cannot read property of undefined`.

e.g.

```
var board = {
    width: 188, 
    height: 110, 
    left: (320 - board.width)/2,
    top: (480 - this.height)/8, 
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that because `board` is not defined until after the object is constructed and the assignment executes. (Also, `this` is not defined outside a function.) You'll have to use more than one statement.

```
var board = { width : 188, height : 110 };
board.left = (320 - board.width) / 2;
board.top = (480 - board.height) / 8;
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative: you could consider using a [immediately invoked function expression](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/):

```
var board = (function(){
    var width = 188 
       ,height = 110;
     return {
          width: width
         ,height: height
         ,left: (320 - width)/2
         ,top: (480 - height)/8
     };
   })();
```